# Detecting numpad keys with pynput keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, hotkeys, pynput, numpad

I'm using pynput keyboard module to detect keystrokes in python app.

At the moment I can't  differentiate numpad keys from regular number keys, they all return as "1", "2", "3", etc

So what am I missing?

code :

```
def on_press(key):
    print key

def on_release(key):
    return

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `vk` attribute of the `key` object to obtain the [virtual key code](http://cherrytree.at/misc/vk.htm), which ranges from 96 to 105 for numbers entered from the numpad keys:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    if hasattr(key, 'vk') and 96 <= key.vk <= 105:
        print('You entered a number from the numpad: ', key.char)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press = on_press) as listener:
     listener.join()
```

Comment: I should have looked on here earlier, but I did figure it out after all by looking at the keycode  __dict__.

So in my implementation I used keyboard.KeyCode(0x60) for example to see if the keycode is num0 (0x60 is num0). 

Anyway this answer is correct, thanks a lot. Hopefully it helps a few people since from googling this question going through hundreds of pages I couldn't find an answer before.